# install php-mcrypt on Centos 6

Tags: centos, mcrypt, epel

I'm trying to install php-mcrypt on my Centos 6.0, 64 bit, php 5.3.3. 
I'm using epel repo `rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm`, the last one.

But after I run `yum install php-mcrypt` I'm getting an error

```
   [root@CentOS-60-64-minimal ~]# yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.kiewel-online.ch
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * extras: centos.kiewel-online.ch
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: centos.kiewel-online.ch
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.1.6-5.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x                                     86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.7-5.el5 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.1.6-5.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error:** Package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           **Requires: php-api = 20041225**
           Installed: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_1.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php-api = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-api = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Why epel doesn't give last mcrypt for me? php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64 is not the latest version on the repo... What can I do?

Comment: Ok, today after I wrote yum install php-mcrypt, everything works well. May be it was some errors on epel. I don't know, but everything is fine now.

Answer (score 3):

> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.1.6-5.el5 will be installed

Pay attention to the `el5`, it means that this package is pulling from the EL5 repo. Make sure that the `epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm` has been installed successfully:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep epel
epel-release-6-5.noarch
```

and the `mirrorlist` (in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`) point to the right path:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

*(`epel-6` instead of `epel-5`)*

Comment: I reinstalled epel few times... Have no ideas why it offer el5 file.  rpm -qa | grep epel and mirrilist are correct [root@CentOS-60-64-minimal ~]# rpm -qa | grep epel
epel-release-6-5.noarch

Comment: Append the content of `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` to your original question.

Comment: Ok, today after I wrote yum install php-mcrypt, everything works well. May be it was some errors on epel. I don't know, but everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone encounters this in future I did this:

Removed the previous EPEL install.
`yum remove epel-release`

Then install the latest version for CentOS 6.

`$ cd /tmp`

`$ wget http://mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/centos/6.6/extras/x86_64/Packages/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

`$ rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

And from then on I just ran the `yum install php-mcrypt` command and php-mcrypt installed fine.

Comment: I also found to fix the above error if you try running `yum clean all` to clear the cash then try to install it again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/libmcrypt/libmcrypt-2.5.7-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/libmcrypt/libmcrypt-devel-2.5.7-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh libmcrypt-*.rpm

I use this for a long time without any problem.